# How to delete an SMS from the inbox in Android programmatically using flutter? anyone can help? Thanks for your helping

Tags: flutter, dart, sms

How to delete an SMS from the inbox in Android programmatically using flutter? anyone can help? Thanks for your helping

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To delete SMS using Flutter in Android,

Consideration:

1. Different Android OS (Android 12, MAUI, Harmony etc) maybe different.
2. Use Native Android JAVA Api and not Flutter itself.

You can try how we do it in link here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically